# Python Keyboard Library is unable to differentiate between 'down' and 'right+down'

Tags: python, keyboard-python

This is my code:

```
import keyboard as kb

def key_selected():
    if kb.is_pressed('shift+s+down'):
        return 'True1' 
    
    elif kb.is_pressed('shift+s+right+down'):
        return 'True2'
    
    else:
        return 'NOTHING' 

while True:
    x = key_selected()
    print(x)
```

It returns True1 even when I press **'shift+s+right+down'**. How can resolve this?

Comment: This may be a simple logic problem.  If the `shift` and `s` and `right` and `down` keys are pressed, then it is _also_ true that the `shift` and `s` and `down` keys are pressed.  Try rearranging your `if` statements so that it checks for the more specific condition first.

Comment: Short answer: reverse the order of your conditions. The combination `"shift+s+right+down"` is a more specific "subset" of `"shift+s+down"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with `elif` is that the condition is tested *only if the previous conditions were `False`*. So when you press `shift + s + down + right`, `if kb.is_pressed('shift+s+down')` is triggered because you have pressed `shift` and `s` and `down`, and the `elif` is ignored.

If you reverse the order so that you check for the *more specific condition* first, it should work just fine.

```
def key_selected():
    if kb.is_pressed('shift+s+right+down'):
        return 'True2' 
    
    elif kb.is_pressed('shift+s+down'):
        return 'True1'
    
    else:
        return 'NOTHING'
```

does what you expect.

Comment: So, it should also work if all elifs are replaced by ifs, right?

Comment: @Saat Yes, but then it will check for all conditions all the time, so the pressing `shift + s + down + right` would trigger that `if` _and_ the `shift + s + down` `if`